# Does the auto-generated "patch" method doesn't work with dev server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've created a pretty simple API that contains both a "get" and an "insert" method and it appears endpoints has auto-generated a "patch" method for me.

However, this patch method doesn't work locally. It returns a "404 OK" and the console says:

```
WARNING  2014-07-05 15:56:25,293 api_config_manager.py:247] No endpoint found for path: posts/v1/update/ahBzfmxvZnR5LXNlZXItNjMychELEgRQb3N0GICAgICAgIAKDA
```

The "update" method is declared as follows:

```
RC = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    PostMessage,
    itemKey=messages.StringField(1, required=True)
)

@endpoints.method(
    RC,
    PostMessage,
    http_method='POST',
    name='update',
    path='update/{itemKey}'
)
```

The patch method works fine when deployed to app engine. Is there anything special that needs to be done to get this to work locally?

*Additionally*, I couldn't find any documentation about this auto-generated method. It seems I stumbled upon it by mere coincidence.

Comment: I just had exactly the same experience.  No documentation about the auto-generated PATCH method, but it appeared when I hit the naming correctly.  The devserver was failing with a 404 so I tried on appspot and it worked as expected.  Google should take credit for a cool feature by telling us about it in the docs.